# Draw line chart using dc js

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I wish to draw a simple line chart of my data, plot the sum of reviews against review dates. Examples I've seen so far are only plotting frequencies http://www.d3noob.org/2013/08/add-line-chart-in-dcjs.html  i.e. number of occurrence of the days. Can someone please show me how I can do that or a link to an example?

```
  var data =  [{review_date:'2013-Feb-1', reviews:40},
               {review_date:'2013-Feb-2', reviews:12},
               {review_date:'2013-Feb-2', reviews:47},
               {review_date:'2013-Feb-3', reviews:71},
               {review_date:'2013-Feb-5', reviews:80},
                review_date:'2013-Feb-5', reviews:13}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your data sorted by date already? Then just create a new dataset and summarize your data there. You can find an example of a simple line chart here:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

Comment: its not sorted by date. Please, how do I do that?

Comment: Hmm, your date is a string, right? If you can change for example 'Feb' into 02, etc. you could compare the string and sort like this: `data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.review_date.localeCompare(b.review_date) })`. I suggest you to have a closer look on JavaScripts array.sort() and its optional sort function.